# Handling Invalid inputs in incoming HTTP calls using python

Tags: python-3.x, http

I have written a python script which accepts the incoming messages from Clients via hTTP post.
I am currently checking the input for a tag named operation.
Requirement is- if the Tag operation is something other than the required one. The python script should send a HTTP 400 Bad request message with some custom message details.
As of now, I have tested using postman and can see if the input tag is with a different value, I can see a http 400 returned, but how to set a custom message? is that possible?

more details -
Here is some more details -
I am getting the following input -

`"operationType": { "vendor": "D1", "operation": "Create" }`
and in my code I have the following check-
Check the operation and vendor -s
`operation = json_object['operationType']['operation'] vendor =   json_object['operationType']['vendor'] #continue based on validation - s #if operation != "Create": #raise Exception("400 Bad Request") if operation == "Create": Success block`

If the input operation is not create the script shows only a hTTP 400 bad request when tested from postman. I would also like to add a message and send to the calling application. is this even possible?
Thank you all for your time.
Thanks
Sugata

Comment: Please add more insights to your question, like the library or framework you are using, the code that you have written to handle this scenario etc. In this state, the question is very shallow.

Comment: @Kris - sorry for that. more details added.